# Where I can find information about how helium gas diffuses through different polymer materials

Tags: material-science, diffusion, inert-gases, polymers

I need more experimental information about helium gas diffusion in solid materials such as different plastics, metals, ceramics etc.

For example I am **scientifically curious** about what is the polymer material with lowest diffusion coefficient all around?

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't find any luck getting an answer here in the next few days, *maybe* Chemistry.SE might be worth a second try (I don't know what is acceptable there, but it could be worth a shot).

Comment: What is the time frame you are talking of, and the amount of leakage that is acceptable. In practice, scuba divers going very deep use Helium in their Mix and they have hoses which do not leak massively Helium... Pressure of 10 bar is exactly the operating pressure, and the hoses are flexible... But it may be significant in your context.

Comment: What about Polyvinylidene chloride (PVDC) instead of fluoride? Did you try it?

Comment: I am not a specialist of the field, but from memory the permeability to Helium and Hydrogen of PVDC is very low. Can't find the data right now...

Comment: Depending on the experimental setup, using metal flex lines might be an option.

Comment: One example would be Swagelok, say the FJ series metal hose.  The 1/4" tubing has a dynamic bend radius of 11cm. Some of the bending issues can be alleviated with longer hoses to yield less bend per unit length, depending on the design of the system.

Comment: @johnfound - Done. I also added a bit on bend radius...

Comment: The question is reworded. Unhold it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the experimental setup, using metal flex lines might be an option.

One example would be Swagelok, say the FJ series metal hose. The 1/4" tubing has a dynamic bend radius of 11cm.

Some of the bending issues can be alleviated with longer hoses to yield less bend per unit length, depending on the design of the system. For example, for two boxes moving relative to each other, rather than having the hose in the plane of movement, use elbows to create a bigger loop of hose up out of the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Handbook of Gas Diffusion in Solids and Melts by J. E. Shelby, ASM International 1996 has a chapter on polymers with lots of data tables. The book is out of print, but you can probably find a library copy or a used copy. Scholes Library at the NYSCC at Alfred University would have a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you may be more interested in the permeability, and not just the diffusion.
(here's a link, http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~woodadam/GCH6101/Diffusion%20and%20permeability%20in%20polymers.pdf)

I find it very interesting that CO2 goes through a rubber ballon faster than Helium.  The reason is that CO2 is more permeable in rubber, not the diffusion in the rubber.

Aluminized mylar seems to to a good job of keeping Helium in.  (If that's what you are interested in.)

Comment: Hm, "aluminized mylar" suggestion does not follows from the cited article. It is clear that the aluminum will stop He effectively, but why not "aluminized teflon"?